# How to make the size of pie chart fixed without using canvas (chart.js)

Tags: angular5, chart.js, pie-chart

I use Angular to make a website and on the website, there is a pie chart. I need to set the size of a pie chart (chart.js). Since I generate a pie chart dynamically, the number of labels of charts would vary. If the size of canvas is fixed, then when there are less labels, the size of chart becomes large; when there are more labels, the pie chart becomes small. Is there a way to make the size of pie chart fixed no matter how many labels I have? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, you can use `maintainAspectRatio: false` in options and then set the width and height via css/sass